# Does the latest version of gazebo work with ROS?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use the latest version of gazebo with ROS like the version that comes with the ROS installation? Because I have some problems and would like to try out the newer one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51493/does-the-latest-version-of-gazebo-work-with-ros?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just asked a similar question on the [answers.gazebo](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/594/when-will-gazebo-be-catkin-ized-in-ros/) site. From my current understanding it is not possible until the ros package maintainers decide to switch it over. There have been some plugin and api changes so I imagine that that is the hold up. Also, there is the desire to catkinize the ROS-Gazebo package before releasing the new version.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-01-04**:
You say that you have version 1.2? I have fuerte and it says 1.0.2. Has groovy a newer version of gazebo?

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-04**:
Ah, I assumed you had the latest version of ROS. Groovy does have a newer version of Gazebo, but not the newest (1.3). With Groovy I can find it here:
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.2